# Is there any Memory limitation for a Windows 8 application as like in windows phone?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am creating a image processing application in Windows 8.

Since am playing with images I wanted to know is there any memory limitation for Windows 8 applications?

Depending on that I can reduce size of image before saving it to memory, how much memory it can take maximum for it's working?

Any information please.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of a hard limit outside of typical process limits, however two things to note:

1. Your app if consuming a larger amount of resources, may be terminated and unloaded while it is suspended, so it's important to implement a proper resume strategy that doesn't take too much time, or your app will fail because of the wait time.
2. Your app can run on a lower powered device. When you submit your app to the Windows Store, on the 'Selling Details' page there is a section at the bottom. If your app consumes a large amount of RAM then I recommend setting this.

[image: Minimum System Ram]